# How to make `make check` process TAP output?

Tags: autotools, tap

I have a C++ program that generates what I believe is minimal TAP output, like this:

```
  TAP version 13
  1..3
  ok 1
  not ok 2
  ok 3
```

This program is called `test_runner` and returns 0.

The `Makefile.am` in the directory is the following:

```
  TESTS = test_runner
  check_PROGRAMS = test_runner
  test_runner_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

Now, when I execute `make check`, the summary output is the following:

```
  # TOTAL: 1
  # PASS:  1
  # SKIP:  0
  # XFAIL: 0
  # FAIL:  0
  # XPASS: 0
  # ERROR: 0
```

My question is: is `make check` supposed to inspect the TAP output of my program (as I would expect to get 2 successes and 1 failure) and if so, what am I doing wrong?

`automake` version is `1.13.3`, `autoconf` version is  `2.69`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have this in your **configure.ac**:

```
AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE([tap-driver.sh])
...
AC_PROG_AWK
```

And this in your **Makefile.am**:

```
check_PROGRAMS = test_runner
test_runner_SOURCES = main.cpp

LOG_DRIVER = env AM_TAP_AWK='$(AWK)' $(SHELL) \
              $(top_srcdir)/tap-driver.sh

TESTS = test_runner
```

The `LOG_DRIVER` variable is what makes it invoke the `tap-driver.sh` script, otherwise the default generic test driver is used. You can optionally [define specific drivers for each file extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Declaring-Custom-Test-Drivers.html#Declaring-Custom-Test-Drivers) (say, one for .py, another for .sh, etc), but in this case, a single global `LOG_DRIVER` is enough.

## UPDATE for automake 1.15

As user **ecerulm** pointed out, `tap-driver.pl` is being deprecated, so I changed the answer to consider only `tap-driver.sh`.

Comment: Awesome. It just works. I'll start from here. The manual is pretty unclear about how to do it in a minimal fashion. Thank you for this concise answer.

Comment: From automake-1.15 the `tap-driver.pl` is kind of deprecated. See [release notes](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2015-01/msg00005.html). Paraphrasing from the release note: awk+shell
    implementation of the TAP driver is more portable and has the same features of the perl one, the awk+shell is the one documented in the manual so they will keep just that one.

Comment: @ecerulm: Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect the newest version.